# Seeking Feedback, Infinite loop

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm practicing some newly acquired skills and wanted to tap the community for some feedback on the code below.

The goal: create a simple program to help an imaginary cashier return the right change by deconstructing the components of the change (dollars, quaters etc). 
The best way I could think of doing this is by using an if statement with a nested while loop.

2 questions:

1). The while loop isnt terminating at the end of the script despite the condition runningTotal != change no longer being satisfied. Why is that exactly? Isn't the while supposed to run until that condition is met, and the be terminated? I must be missing something...Is there something obvious that I'm missing that you guys/gals see?

2). I'm still a beginner (as you could probably tell). What feedback do you have for me on the script below. Things I did well, poorly or just general thoughts. I'm really trying to get better so your comments are much appreciated. Thanks!

The Script:

```
def changeCalc(cost,pmt):
    change = float(pmt - cost)
    print("Total Change: " + str(change))
    runningTotal = 0 #used to count up the change paid in the while loop below

    #make sure they paid enough
    if (pmt - cost) < 0:
        print("The customer needs to pay " + str(abs(change)) + " more.")
    else:
        #check to see if any change is due
        while runningTotal != change:
            #how many DOLLAR bills to return
            dollarBills = int(change - runningTotal)
            print("Number of Dollar Bills: " + str(dollarBills))

            #add to runningTotal
            runningTotal = float(runningTotal + dollarBills)
            print runningTotal

            #how many QUARTERS to return
            numOFqtrs = int((change - runningTotal)/(.25))
            print("Number of Quarters: " + str(numOFqtrs))

            #add to running total
            runningTotal = float(runningTotal + (numOFqtrs * (.25)))
            print runningTotal

            #how many DIMES
            numOFdimes = int((change - runningTotal)/(.10))
            print("Number of Dimes: " + str(numOFdimes))
            runningTotal = float(runningTotal + (numOFdimes * (.10)))

            #how many NICKELS
            print runningTotal
            numOFnickels = int((change - runningTotal)/(.05))
            print("Number of nickels: " + str(numOFnickels))
            runningTotal = float(runningTotal + (numOFnickels * (.05)))
            print runningTotal

            #how many PENNIES
            numOFpennies = int((change - runningTotal)/(.01))
            print("Number of Pennies: " + str(numOFpennies))
            runningTotal = float(runningTotal + (numOFpennies * (.01)))

            print runningTotal
            print change
            #####WHY DOES THE LOOP NOT END HERE??????????##########

            break
```

running changeCalc(87.63,103.86) results in an infinite loop with the following output.

```
Total Change: 16.23
Number of Dollar Bills: 16
16.0
Number of Quarters: 0
16.0
Number of Dimes: 2
16.2
Number of nickels: 0
16.2
Number of Pennies: 3
16.23
16.23
```

Comment: It's generally bad to check for equality with floats, particularly for 1/10ths which can't be represented exactly. Maybe consider using integers for cents rather than floats for dollars.

Comment: Or you could use Decimal http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the problem with your `while` loop is with floating point precision: `runningTotal` is *very close*, but just not quite the same as `change`. You can solve this by using some small *epsilon* for comparison, or using integers or similar.

However, it seems you do not need the `while` loop at all, do you? Also, note that the code for the different types of coins is all the same, so you could instead use a loop to iterate over all the different types of coins:

```
COINS = (("Dollars", 1.), 
         ("Quarters", .25), 
         ("Dimes",    .10), 
         ("Nickels",  .05), 
         ("Pennies",  .01))

def changeCalc(cost, pmt):
    change = pmt - cost
    print("Total Change: %.2f" % change)
    if (pmt - cost) < 0:
        print("The customer needs to pay %.2f more." % abs(change))
    else:
        runningTotal = 0
        for (name, value) in COINS:
            number = int((change - runningTotal) / value)
            if number > 0:
                print("Number of %s: %d" % (name, number))
                runningTotal += number * value
        print runningTotal, change, (runningTotal - change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing change-runningTotal and you will see that it is of the order of 10e-15 . This is probabaly due to the use of floats.
You can change the condition of the loop to:
"while runningTotal - change <-0.001 or runningTotal - change >0.001:"
for the program to work.